# MVC4 input field maxlength

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm showing placeholder from model like

```
@Html.TextBox("",ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, 
    new { placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

from `Shared\EditorTemplates folder and call it String.cshtml`.

Now i want to set the maxlength from Model instead of putting in my view like below.

In My Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Community Code")]
[Display(Prompt = "Enter Company Code")]
[StringLength(6)]
public string COMPANYCODE { get; set; }
```

View :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.COMPANYCODE, new { @maxlength = "4" })
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I changed My model and String.cshtml like below

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Community Code")]
[Display(Prompt = "Enter Community Code")]
[AdditionalMetadata("MaxLength", 4)]
public string COMPANYCODE { get; set; }
```

String.cshtml

```
@{
    string maxLength = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("MaxLength")
        ? ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["MaxLength"].ToString() : null;
}

 @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
       new { placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark, @class = "form-control", maxlength = maxLength })
```

View:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.COMPANYCODE)
```

it's worked.